# On keeping our site's set of tags in the best possible shape

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some of you may have noticed me getting a bit crankier than usual in the past two days about what I think make good tags and bad tags. I think maintaining a good useful set of tags is important to be a good useful Stack Exchange site.

But since I couldn't find a great set of guidelines on this topic I went ahead and asked a general question about it over on meta.SO using some examples of two of our newest tags that I think are not great:

> [Guidelines for maintaining the set of tags on a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199361)

So this is more of a pointer to the question but if you think it's important I can change this into a localized version of that question.

Discussion welcome both here and there. If here it should be more about our site, if there it should be more about the general topic of maintaining the set of tags on an SE site.

Comment: See: **[Why do we tag questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776)**

Comment: See: **[Tag Folksonomy and Tag Synonyms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)**

Comment: See: **[Improved Tagging](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/)**

Comment: I, Halabi, as the most lovely user in Travel.SE, give you full authority to mess up with tags the way you want.

Comment: Hehe I used the synonym [suggest feature to suggest "toilet usage" as a synonym of "hygiene"](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/hygiene/synonyms) but it seemed like a good time to check how we manage our tag now that we've been growing and growing.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I noticed that some of the sister, stack exchange sites use tag suggestions when composing a question. I found this to be a rather convenient way of choosing the right tag.

I really don't know how this works, but I do see the benefit of applying tag suggestions on travel.se

I would never came up with the tag "cell-phones", when I would ask a mobile phone question question. I would either use "gsm" or "mobile-telephone" as tag, leading to more anger for @hippietrail ;)

I honestly believe that having this tag suggestion would lead to less but more descriptive tags available.

I don't know what it takes.

*EDIT*
Just noticed Stackoverflow uses tag suggestion as well. I made a screen dump. Notice that I did not use the word "svn" in my text, yet for some reason I am getting that suggestion, suggesting that there it is more to it then using words in the OP:

[image: screendump of stackoverflow]

Comment: I think you'll find that some of the tags you would use are already [synonyms for "cell-phones"](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/cellphones/synonyms). I'm pretty sure I argued against "cell-phones" in favour of "mobile-phones". Anyway it's one of the tags on my ignore list because I never want to travel with a phone.